# Negative Binomial - Application problem

Tags: probability

The digits after the decimal point of a random number between 0 and 1 are number selected at random, with replacement, independently, and successively from the set {0,1,2,...,9}.

In a random number from (0,1) on average, how many digits are there before the fifth 3?

Answer is 49.

I though this would have a negative binomial distribution with parameters r = 5 and p = 0.1. Giving an expected value of r/p = 50... 
Confused as to why the answer is 49. Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are almost right. The mean number of digits up to **and including** the fifth $3$ is $50$. The mean number **before** the fifth $3$ is therefore $49$.